# Quelle est l'origine de l'expression "prendre la mouche" pour exprimer la rage ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Je comprends que l'expression **prendre la mouche** veut exprimer la rage de quelqu'un qui vient de se fâcher, mais quelle est l'origine ? pourquoi la mouche dans ce cas ?

Answer (score 2):

[Linternaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/344/prendre-la-mouche/) explique que déjà:

> Au XVIe siècle, la ***mouche*** désignait un souci, une pensée négative qui arrivait brusquement.

Mais l'esxpression est née plus tard. Le site [ProjetVoltaire](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiIhOzMpdHxAhXNOewKHUeBC4YQFjACegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.projet-voltaire.fr%2Forigines%2Fexpression-prendre-la-mouche%2F&usg=AOvVaw21ffRYFnUXPIp2ZZ1QXONK) nous fournit plus de détails:

> Quel peut-être le rapport entre l’insecte volant et le fait de se
> mettre en colère ? Pour comprendre l’expression ***prendre la mouche***,
> il nous faut revenir avant le XVIIe siècle et voir l’usage du mot ***mouche***.
>
> Autrefois, on utilisait ce terme pour désigner différents insectes
> volants. La ***mouche aux bœufs*** qualifiait le *taon*, on parlait de
> ***mouche à miel*** pour *l’abeille*, de ***mouche à chien*** pour la *tique* ou
> encore de ***mouche cornue*** pour le *scarabée*.
>
> On imagine aisément que la mouche qui a inspiré notre expression doit
> être ***la mouche aux bœufs***. En effet, elle ***provoque une réaction si
> vive, imprévisible et exagérée sous l’effet de la douleur qu’elle fait
> penser à un soudain accès de colère***.
>
> On trouve d’ailleurs le sens de cette formule dans la quatrième
> édition du dictionnaire de l’Académie française, en 1762
>
> > On dit aussi ***prendre la mouche*** pour dire ***se piquer, se fâcher sans sujet***.
> > Et lorsque quelqu’un s’emporte, se met en colère sans que l’on sache
> > pourquoi, on demande
> >
> > - Quelle mouche l’a piqué ?

J'ai été surprise te trouver une date encore plus ancienne pour cette expression:

> Cette expression date du milieu du XVIIe siècle (*mais ***prendre
> mouskes*** existait déjà au XIVe*).   Et pour expliquer encore plus la
> naissance d'une telle expression, il est intéressant de savoir qu'au
> XVIe siècle, ***mouche*** employé au figuré désignait aussi ***une
> pensée brusque ou un souci.***
>
> - (...) ayant peu d'esprit, il ne
>   discernait pas les tons et les caractères, et prenait souvent la
>   mouche sur rien. Jean-Jacques Rousseau - Les confessions

([Expressio.fr](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/prendre-la-mouche))